# Colocar Texto na Borda Div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Queria colocar um texto sobre a borda, como na imagem em anexo. Estou usando Bootstrap.

[image: Div com Borda.]

Meu código atual está assim:

CSS:

```
.jumbotronmax {
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    color:inherit;
    /* background-color:#ccc */
}
.jumbotronmax .h1,.jumbotronmax h1 {
    color:inherit
}
.jumbotronmax p {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:200
}
.jumbotronmax>hr {
    border-top-color:#d5d5d5
}
.container .jumbotronmax,.container-fluid .jumbotronmax {
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000;
}
.jumbotronmax .container {
    max-width:100%
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .jumbotronmax {
        padding-top:48px;
        padding-bottom:48px
    }
    .container .jumbotronmax,.container-fluid .jumbotronmax {
        padding-right:60px;
        padding-left:60px
    }
    .jumbotronmax .h1,.jumbotronmax h1 {
        font-size:63px
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="osindel" class="topico">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotronmax">
                <h1>Teste</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6):

CSS:

```css
.fieldset-border {
  border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
  padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

.fieldset-border .legend-border {
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset-border">
  <legend class="legend-border">Teste</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Exemplo: [Exemplo no jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murilosrg/yzz4eehx/)

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado :D