# Como fazer Borda da imagem abaixo?

Tags: html, css

[image: Foto Border]

essa é minha primera pergunta no stackoverflow, agradeço quem me ajudar :)

Comment: Acho que esse link resolve sua dúvida https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213100/colocar-texto-na-borda-div

Comment: valeu meu sonegado

Answer (score 1):

HTML 4 e 5 voce pode usar `<legend>`:

```html
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Exemplo:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="A" name="rdo">
    <label for="A">A</label><br/>

    <input type="radio" id="B" name="rdo">
    <label for="B">B</label><br/>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

caso contrario voce pode usar dessa forma:

```css
.fieldset-border {
  border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
  padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

.fieldset-border .legend-border {
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset-border">
  <legend class="legend-border">Teste</legend>
</fieldset>
```

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213100/colocar-texto-na-borda-div/213114#213114)